# How to add php source to maven java project in NetBeans?

Tags: java, php, netbeans

I program in Java with all its many specialty jar additions.  But my database is MySQL located on a shared host (HostGator) which only allows PHP. (Yes, they will host JSP but its very expensive compared to PHP).  In order to execute SQL from Java, I open a HttpURLConnection and send it the name of the php file to run, which does the SQL query.

My question is about NetBeans.  I can either create a PHP project or a Java project, but how to create a Java project and add in php source code?  I've been doing the php in a separate editor but would like it to all be in NetBeans.

Comment: Ok, so I manually added a folder called php under <projectname>\src\main.  Then in NetBeans, right-click Source Packages and select New>Other...>Other>Empty File. Click Next. Browse to created php folder.  Then name it filename.php.  Doing that created a file in the project tree in Other Sources>php>filename.php.  But now what if I want to add a php source file from a library that is not directly part of the project?  The Browse button only allows selection from within the project.

Comment: use a different code editor that supports multiple languages, eg, VS Code or Atom

Comment: @VaibhavVishal NetBeans NetBeans formally supports both Java and PHP, so why are you advising the use of "a different code editor"? In what way would that be better than just using NetBeans?

Comment: [1] Select your Java project in the **Projects** panel. [2] Do **File > Open File...** and select your external PHP file. It should open in an edit window. [3] Do **File > Save As...** to save a copy of that PHP file in whatever location you want within your Java project.